# WPF datagrid shows horizontal scroll bar when the actual width of datagrid equals to the sum of actual width of all columns' actual width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I run into the problem as the title says. I have datagrid inside a scroll viewer in a wpf window. I tried using tools like Snoop to see the actual width of the datagrid and the actual width of each column. I set the width of each column to "*" and *HorizontalScrollBarVisibility* property to Auto in xaml.
My xaml code is

```xml
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="scrollViewer"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid
        Name="dataGrid"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ActualHeight}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="White"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
        ColumnWidth="*"
        EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
        EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        MinColumnWidth="120"
        RowHeight="30"
        SelectionUnit="Cell"
        UseLayoutRounding="False"
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here are width data I got from Snoop.
The actual width of scroll viewer.
[image: The actual width of scroll viwer]

The actual width of datagrid.
[image: The actual width of DataGrid]

[image: I have 5 columns]

[image: The actual width of each column]

Actually, the actual width of scrollviewer equals to the actual width of datagrid. But it still shows the horizontal scroll bar. ***The strange thing is when I drag the scroll bar, it disappers***.

After I removed the scroll viewer, I found that the horizontal scroll bar still exists. So the horizontal bar is belongs to the datagrid. As the picture above showed, The sum of the actual width of 5 columns, which is 5 * 204.8 = 1024, is equal to the actual width of the datagrid.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Why do you wrap the DataGrid into a ScrollViewer? This doesn't make sense as the DataGrid already has its own ScrollViewer. Your wrapping ScrollViewere will also interfere with the DataGrid's virtualization. Simply don't wrap it. Just assign a fix size to the DataGrid so that the overflow content becomes scrollable.

Comment: I removed the scrollviewer and the phenomenon described still exists

Comment: You must restrict the size of the DataGrid, either by setting Width and Height of the DataGrid explicitly or by the layout arrangement of the parent container. Now when the column/row count/die exceeds the viewport of the DataGrid the ScrollViewer can do its job.

Comment: I do not want the scrollviewer of the datagrid shows because the space is wide enough to place these columns but the horizontal scroll bar still shows and it will disappear when I drag it. That is the matter.

Comment: How does your current layout look like? Have you assigned a fixed size to the DataGrid as suggested? Please show the current version of your DataGrid and the parent container.

Comment: This problem fixed finally. It is caused by the user defined datagrid style. A border with width 1,1,0,0 was placed at the left of the DataGrid's ItemsPresenter.